# KDL IKSolver (Only for Destination Orientation)

Tags: ros, ik, kdl, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use KDL for inverse kinematics calculations of 5 axis CNC machines.
5 axis CNC machines has 2 rotational axis and 3 translational axes.

I am going to define kinematics chain in KDL library and i only care about orietation of tool.
The translational axes has no effect for orientation so i can discard them.

Initialy tool orientation vector is 0,0,1.
I want tool vector to get parellel to for example vector 1,0,0.
How can i get joint variables for this situation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202415/kdl-iksolver-(only-for-destination-orientation)/) by [Kadir Canik](https://answers.ros.org/users/21278/kadir-canik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know whether KDL can do IK with less than 6 DoF; I've had good results using OpenRAVE's ikfast module for that (with the TranslationDirection5D plugin type).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-04**:
I know that at least some of KDLs IK methods do support chains with less than 6 DOF. I've used [pydl_utils](http://wiki.ros.org/pykdl_utils) several times for 2, 3, and 5 DOF manipulators.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-04**:
I believe the `inverse` method in `pykdl_utils` eventually calls KDL's general [Newton-Raphson IK solver](http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/%7Ersmits/kdl/api/html/classKDL_1_1ChainIkSolverPos__NR.html)

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-05**:
Good to know, thanks!